# Testing method for the performance of R&D support program

Tags: econometrics, self-study, technology, difference-in-difference

Suppose that Government aims to initiate R&D support program to firms

The objective of the support program is to rise R&D expenditures and productivity.

I have the following data variables:

Q: Output
K: Capital
L: Number of labors
RD: R&D expenditures (total)
S: Support status (if supported, 1)(if not, 0)

This is panel data.

How can I test this objective? Which econometric analysis should I apply in order to test this objective? (Dif in Dif, or which regressions?)

note: I prefer to apply Diff in Diff method for Q (output) and also for RD (expenditure). As I read some articles about this, I see Tobit or Probit regression models where RD is taken as independent variable. But I have no idea why these regression models are applied. This is not econometrics courses. I don't have enough econometrics background. ( I only perfectly know time series )

I do not expect theoretically construction of estimation methods. I just want to learn about which methods are suitable for this objective.

Comment: This looks like school assignment can you please first share your ideas of what would be the best thing to do here?

Comment: I have data set. I will apply econometric estimation methods. I try to only search for your professional ideas. @1muflon1

Comment: o see no reason why you could not provide us with your attempt at constructing the model. Just say how do you think the model should look like eg y=a+b(R&D) … etc you don’t need to worry about getting it wrong but we have a rule that homework questions must show attempt before getting answers

Comment: okay I added my ideas in the question part. Please can you share your ideas with me? @1muflon1 Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sorry, this is not econometrics assignment, therefore I don't expect theoretically construction of the model. I also dont know how to construct the model. This is just R&D economics course. And accordingly, I just want to know application side. That's, I want to learn which methods are suitable for testing this objective? @1muflon1